# How to set external style for text block based on the language set by the user in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

**My windows phone 8 application should work in two languages English and Arabic.**
In this application i used text block control in many places i.e. in List Boxes and also as individual for Page Headers.

```
<!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock x:Name="title" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.CategoriesText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Fonts/nazli.ttf#nazli"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Now in List Box also i have text block.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Background="White">
        <ListBox x:Name="categoriesList"  
                 SelectionChanged="categoriesList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="categoryGrid" Height="60" Margin="0,0,0,0"  MinWidth="480" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RowColour}}" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                            <!--<RowDefinition Height="10"/>-->
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>                            

                        <StackPanel x:Name="dataRow" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="category" Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" MinWidth="420"/>                                
                            <Image x:Name="arrow" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="{Binding ArrowImageName}" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <!--<Image  x:Name="line" Grid.Row="1" Width="460" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/separator.png"  />-->
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

By default the application is in **English** language. So I want to use the default Font Family **Segoe WP** for all Text Blocks when the application is in English.

When the user changes the Application's Language from English to Arabic, then I want to use the embedded Font **nazli.ttf** for all Text Blocks in the application.

So for that I embedded one external font in my application and set the content type to **Copy Always**. The font is **nazli.ttf**.

**Blow is the external style which works for English. But I need an External resource which should work for both English and Arabic Languages.**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<Style x:Key="NormalTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe WP"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So how should be the external resource file to satisfy the above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a converter on the TextBlocks:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FontConverter}}">some text</TextBlock>
```

converter:

```
public class FontConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (culture.Name.StartsWith("ar"))
        {
            return new FontFamily("/MyApp;Component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#fontName");
        }
        else
        {
            return new FontFamily("Segoe WP");
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Adjust the paths above as appropriate.

And the converter declared somewhere as:

```
<converters:FontConverter x:Key="FontConverter" />
```